# Sending mail from PHP

Tags: php, web-server

I used this code all around my projects and it works fine:

```
mail("email@domain.com", "Subject", "message");
```

Now, I´m developing on php and if I use this code, the message is not sent, but it works correctly from the terminal.

Am I missing something?

[UPDATE]

I send the mail from the terminal like this:

```
echo "Test email" | mail -s "My Subject" email@domain.com
```

Comment: Make sure that in your php.ini you have `display_errors` on, and `error_reporting` turned up to `E_ALL`, and let us know if there are any errors.

Comment: there is no error on /var/log/httpd/error_log and I did what you said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to send a well formed email with PHP, especially if you want to use more advanced feature like attached files. And the risk to pass in spam with possibly bad header or content is high.

I really advise you to use SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) which is an excellent PHP library to send emails.

Comment: It is not my php application, I am suppose to bring it "online" as well as I can so I cann´t touch any code....

Comment: That's not a problem, you just have to put the SwiftMailer directory somewhere in your project, then use `require` to include it in your code. It's compatible with any project.

Comment: Finally we speak with developers and the are going to use this library. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Include the Header field as:

$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you think the problem is and why you think this will fix it?

Comment: I did, it says "Message sent" but I don´t receive any message.

Comment: echo was just to display some message.
Copy the above code in <?php ?> tags. save in a .php file and call it from terminal like php filename.php and check if the mail is delivered.

Comment: I did and I have this answer: php testmail.php. RESULT:
sh: -t: command not found

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a system with SELINUX Enforcing then you may need to tell SELINUX to let php send mail.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1
```

Comment: I did and it says: setsebool:  SELinux is disabled. I tried after that and still no mail is send.

Comment: Okay yes, SELinux is disabled then this answer will have no effect as you have observed.